# SUMPRODUCT works for limited range but not when I try to extend it?

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula

So I've got a matrix with countries and their corresponding regions on the far left 2 columns and top 2 rows.

When I tested out Sumproduct on a small (7x8) bit of the matrix, I got the correct result (in this case, 100). Here's the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!A3:$A10="Asia")*('THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!C1:J1="Asia")*'THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!C3:J10)
```

However, when I tried to extend it to the entire matrix, I'm getting #N/A as the result! It should be at least 100.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!A3:A245="Asia")*('THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!C1:IK1="Asia")*'THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!C3:IK245)
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a cell with an error within the extended range?

Comment: I don't think so. I just added a column and did =SUM across every row. There weren't any errors that popped up

Comment: It worked OK for me. Check for NA errors in A3:A245 and C1:IK1 as those will propagate through the SUMPRODUCT too (but may not have been in your SUM test to find errors). Just do a Find on the sheet for N/A.

Comment: Ooh, I got it! There were errors in the A3:A245 range - I was only looking in the matrix with the data, not with the headers. Thanks!!!

Comment: If either of you wants to submit that as an answer, I can close this thread :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get N/A! from a sumproduct if any of the cells it refers to has N/A!. Check the data matrix, the row headers, and the column headers for N/A!